# Make cases come after each other in one row

Tags: cases

I want to know how to make cases come after each other in one row, separated by a \Leftrightarrow instead of underneath each other.

```
   \begin{cases} 
    S_{x}k + S_{y}t = q \\
    S_{x}a + S_{b} = p \\ 
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{cases} 
    S_{x} + S_{y} \frac{p}{k} = \frac{q}{k} \\
    S_{y} \left( \frac{b}{a} - \frac{p}{k} \right) = \frac{p}{a} - \frac{q}{k} \\
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{cases} 
    S_{x} + S_{y} \frac{p}{k} = \frac{q}{k} \\
    S_{y} = \frac{pk - qa}{bk - pa} \\
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{cases} 
   S_{x} = \frac{p^{2} - bq}{ap -bk} \\
    S_{y} = \frac{pk - qa}{bk - pa} \\
\end{cases}
```

Comment: to format as a code block here indent by four spaces or just highlight and use the  `{}` button which will indent it for you. Inline code like `\foo` mark with backticks `\`\foo\` `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that cases are displayed math ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{dcases}
    S_{x}k + S_{y}t = q \\
    S_{x}a + S_{b} = p \
\end{dcases}
\quad
\Leftrightarrow
\qquad
\begin{dcases}
    S_{x} + S_{y} \dfrac{p}{k} = \dfrac{q}{k} \\
    S_{y} \left( \dfrac{b}{a} - \dfrac{p}{k} \right) = \dfrac{p}{a} - \dfrac{q}{k}
\end{dcases}
\quad
\Leftrightarrow
\qquad
\begin{dcases}
    S_{x} + S_{y} \dfrac{p}{k} = \dfrac{q}{k} \\
    S_{y} = \dfrac{pk - qa}{bk - pa}
\end{dcases}
\quad
\Leftrightarrow
\qquad
\begin{dcases}
   S_{x} = \dfrac{p^{2} - bq}{ap -bk} \\
    S_{y} = \dfrac{pk - qa}{bk - pa}
\end{dcases}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I use the \usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}, I get a frame around my entire document. If I dont use it, the cases wont look that good.

Comment: I change to \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}, It solved it.

Comment: The option `showframe` is only to show page layout and where `cases` are. Of course, in real document it had to be omitted. The looks of cases is in both cases the same :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `\hfill $\Leftrightarrow$ \hfill` between each `cases` environment to create a stretchable space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

$\begin{cases} 
    S_{x}k + S_{y}t = q \\
    S_{x}a + S_{b} = p \\ 
\end{cases}$
\hfill
$\Leftrightarrow$
\hfill
$\begin{cases} 
    S_{x} + S_{y} \frac{p}{k} = \frac{q}{k} \\
    S_{y} \left( \frac{b}{a} - \frac{p}{k} \right) = \frac{p}{a} - \frac{q}{k} \\
\end{cases}$
\hfill
$\Leftrightarrow$
\hfill
$\begin{cases} 
    S_{x} + S_{y} \frac{p}{k} = \frac{q}{k} \\
    S_{y} = \frac{pk - qa}{bk - pa} \\
\end{cases}$
\hfill
$\Leftrightarrow$
\hfill
$\begin{cases} 
   S_{x} = \frac{p^{2} - bq}{ap -bk} \\
    S_{y} = \frac{pk - qa}{bk - pa} \\
\end{cases}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The last case goes right under the first one, is there a way to make a gap between?

Comment: \vfill made the gap to big

Comment: nvm vspace fixed it.

Comment: In your question, you said you want to makes cases environment in one row. So you must use `\hfill`, `\vfill` is used to make vertical  stretching space.

Comment: The length of gap depend on  text width.